# Not showing option to boot from thumb drive in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot

I have a TAILS Thumb Drive. I used it with Windows but I can't figure out how to get GRUB to boot from the Thumb Drive when I have it installed. My boot menu only gives me the options to run GNOME or UBUNTU LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide: https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/ or alternatively the program Yumi has an option to directly download and create the bootable USB drive for you. download at: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

If you already have a bootable .iso installed on your thumb drive chances are GRUB is already installed. Change your bios to boot first from your USB drive or alternatively find the hotkey **that you press during boot-up** that lets you select which drive to boot from and select your thumb drive.

For many: Rapidly tap F11 during boot

For Toshiba: http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?soid=403623

For HP: http://h10010.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01443326

> > In my case I mashed all the buttons then rebooted and repeated until i found that F7 opens up a boot menu, then i scrolled down to my USB drive and click enter. and it then boots using the thumb drive.
> >
> > If you give up with USB install try burning it onto a CDROM, I have heard that on some computers you need to turn on legacy support in the bios, or turn on the boot menu in bios and only then will the above mentioned hotkey work

Comment: My F12 Boot Menu is already configured to look for the thumb drive boot first. I guess GRUB just doesn't seem to find it. It worked with Windows so I know the TAILS ISO is installed properly on the thumb drive. Does this mean I need to burn GRUB onto the thumb drive that contains TAILS?

Comment: I'll try to reinstall TAILS with one of the listed programs. I tried every F# key and couldn't find a menu of bootable drives. It seems like GRUB is just not giving me the option to boot from the thumb drive.

Comment: okay... i think i've tried almost everything. I have an Acer Aspire M5. i just reinstalled TAILS using YUMI and still no joy. When i start up - no matter what F# key i press - i get the GRUB 2.0 boot menu with options:  Ubuntu 14.04, Advanced Options for Ubuntu 14.04 and System Setup. Even though in System Setup I have my USB Drive listed first I cannot seem to get the computer to load TAILS prior to the GRUB boot menu. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have deleted all my comments (could you please do the same?) because this was getting very messy. send me an email at 1@leathan.net and I will try to help you or just wait and hope someone helps you. I wish you best of luck. Tails is very awesome! dont give up!!